# Skype answer button appearing off screen on multi monitor Linux setup

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, skype

Im using Linux Mint LMDE and have Skype installed, running KDE desktop.

I have 4 monitors connected of varying sizes.

The issue that I'm having is that when Skype rings, there is no button to click answer. I think it's appearing off screen somewhere.

Since the answer button is not a whole application but just a part of Skype, there is no task bar tray icon for it.

Currently, the only way for me to know who is calling is to wait for the ringing to stop and see who rang in the *Missed Calls* section of Skype.

I would like to be able to see who is calling and answer the calls. How can I get that answer button to appear within a visible screens limits?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:  When you hear Skype ring, run a script that acts as follows: (1) Get Skype pid number, (2) Get list of all windows, along with process pids, (3) Using pid (or possibly window name) find appropriate window id, (4) bring that window to current screen and raise it.

For (1), you could use the usual `ps ... | grep ...` approach.  It isn't clear to me what sort of window or box the "answer button" is in; it may be that using a window title (instead of a pid) to find the relevant window in `wmctrl -l` output might work better.  For (2), `wmctrl -lp`.  For (4), `wmctrl -R ...`

On this system I don't have Skype or multiple monitors, so cannot test above suggestions.  I think a more-streamlined method can be worked out.

In creating and testing such a script, it might be a good idea to create a stand-in process that you can park off-screen and try using `wmctrl` manually to bring it on-screen, before trying to script the process.

Regarding the "When you hear Skype ring, run a script" portion of the answer above:  If you want to make a menu button such that the script runs when you move the mouse cursor across the button, examples of doing so using [yume3](http://yume3.sourceforge.net/) are found in 
scripts `typewriter` and `yume-wmctrl-leftcol` which are in yume3-22.gz at yume3's [download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yume3/files/).   yume3 is Gtk-based, and easy to install if your system has Gtk libraries already installed on it.  yume3 has option settings to make menus sticky / on-top / undecorated, as explained [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yume3/forums/forum/1694372/topic/4471313).

Answer (score 0):

One thing to explore:
In KDE 4.5.5, System Settings, under Hardware, Display and Monitor, Multiple Monitors,  there is a setting "Show unmanaged Windows on:" and a box that for me displays these choices: Display1,Display2,Display3,Display with pointer.

I'm not sure of the definition of "unmanaged Windows" would fit here, but you could try setting that to one option or the other.

Another possibility is to explore command line arguments to Skype. I do not have Skype installed at the moment.
In other X programs there is frequently a command line option like --geometry, that can specify the size of the window as well as the coordinates that it will start at.  Opera works this way, Xterm, and several others do to.  I do not know from personal experience if Skype has that, but the thought is if you specify a start up location that is on a certain display, when a call comes in maybe it would stick to that display for the notification window.

Sorry this is not a definitive answer, instead just 2 things to explore...